# sql injection vulnerabilidad

Tags: php

Tengo una vulnerabilidad de inyección SQL en mi formulario de inicio de sesión, cuando pongo '# en el campo de nombre de usuario, no es necesario poner la contraseña para iniciar sesión. He usado vega y OWASP ZAP para saber dónde está mal el código y lo ha detectado pero no sé como sanitizarlo para que no suceda esto, aquí mi código:

```
function check_login($username, $pass, $vuln = False)
{
  if ($vuln)
  {
      $query = sprintf("SELECT * from `users` where `login` like '%s'
            and `password` = SHA1( CONCAT('%s', `salt`)) limit 1;",
            $username,
            mysql_real_escape_string($pass));
  }
  else
  {
      $query = sprintf("SELECT * from `users` where `login` like '%s'
            and `password` = SHA1( CONCAT('%s', `salt`)) limit 1;",
            mysql_real_escape_string($username),
            mysql_real_escape_string($pass));
  }
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if ($res)
  {
      return mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
  }
  else
  {
      if ($vuln)
      {
    die(mysql_error());
      }
      else
      {
    return False;
      }
  }
}
```

La parte que el sofware me detecta está mal es:

```
$username,
mysql_real_escape_string($pass));
```

y:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($username),
mysql_real_escape_string($pass));
```

¿pueden ayudarme?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si quieres evitar la inyección SQL, jamás, y digo ***JAMÁS*** concatenes valores introducidos por el usuario en tus queries. Utiliza [Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) y por el amor de todo lo que es sagrado en programación, ***ACTUALÍZATE!!!***. Estás usando `mysql_query` aun??? [***ESTO LLEVA DEPRECADO DESDE PHP 5.5***](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)! Si utilizas cosas que ya están obsoletas, es difícil que sea seguro! Échale un ojo a [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) hazte el favor.

Comment: Vos estas diciendo que tu query devuelve valores con el campo de pass vacio y como nombre de usuario #.. pero el query devuelve valores?

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas! Le coloqué un mysql_real_escape_string($username) y está resuelto. Ahora tengo que cambiar todas las funciones a mysqi_quere sí. Muchas gracias de nuevo!